# BIND not working - suspected problem with query engine

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a [long query](https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/ySHnU3) but the relevant parts are shown here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... (concat(?height_statue_in_meters, ' m (', ?height_statue_in_feet, ' ft)') AS ?height_of_statue) (concat(?total_height_in_meters, ' m (', ?total_height_in_feet, ' ft)') AS ?total_height) ...
WHERE { 
...
BIND(coalesce(?height_statue_m, ?height_statue_m_calc) AS ?height_statue_in_meters)
BIND(coalesce(?height_statue_ft, ?height_statue_ft_calc) AS ?height_statue_in_feet)
BIND(coalesce(?height_pedestal_m, ?height_pedestal_m_calc) AS ?height_pedestal_in_meters)
BIND(coalesce(?height_pedestal_ft, ?height_pedestal_ft_calc) AS ?height_pedestal_in_feet)
BIND(( ?height_statue_in_meters + ?height_pedestal_in_meters ) AS ?total_height_in_meters)
BIND(( ?height_statue_in_feet + ?height_pedestal_in_feet ) AS ?total_height_in_feet)
} ...
```

The first four `BIND` statements use either an available value (in meters or feet) or a calculated one (meters from feet or vice versa). They are working as can be seen by the output variable `?height_of_statue` (containing values in meters and feet) having (correct) values.

The last two `BIND` statements however lead to empty cells for the output variable `?total_height` (containing values in meters and feet) which I can't explain.

I therefore suspect that there might be something wrong with the query engine.
Could this be or am I overlooking something?

(Removing the `concat()` or tentative changes to the last `BIND` statements did not make me any wiser.)

Comment: it's not an engine issue but your query - the unit is attached to the `psn` node, not the height statement itself. See as a sketch here: `?statue wdt:P31/(wdt:P279)* wd:Q179700 .
?statue p:P2048 ?ped_stmt . 
?ped_stmt pq:P518 wd:Q12014132 .
?ped_stmt psn:P2048 ?height_node_ped. 
?height_node_ped wikibase:quantityUnit wd:Q11573 ;
 wikibase:quantityAmount ?height_ped .
  
?statue p:P2048 ?stat_stmt .
?stat_stmt pq:P518 wd:Q179700 .
?stat_stmt psn:P2048 ?height_node_statue. 
?height_node_statue wikibase:quantityUnit wd:Q11573 ;
wikibase:quantityAmount ?height_statue .`

Comment: also should also consider absence of e.g. pedestal height, in that case the total height would be null, not sure if this is intended in your case or if you just consider what you get and treat the rest as 0

Comment: Thank you. Stupid of me to think the issue were the BIND statements. I had switched to using psn for meters but apparently was sloppy doing so.
And yes, if pedestal height is not available, total height should not be available.